# What resources exist for compiling a list of solo piano works considered to be part of the "standard repertoire" or canon?

Tags: classical-music, piano

I'm attempting to compile a list of solo piano works considered to be part of the "standard repertoire" or canon. Does anyone have any tips on books, websites, journal articles, etc. that might attempt the same, or at least, that would help me in my effort?

I'm primarily interested as a listener, but suspect I could derive value from lists compiled for performers as well.

Thus far I've found:

1. [The TalkClassical Top 200 Recommended Solo Keyboard Works](http://www.talkclassical.com/16620-tc-top-200-recommended.html)
2. [The Great Courses: *23 Greatest Solo Piano Works*](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/the-23-greatest-solo-piano-works.html)
3. Trinity College London's Piano Repertoire lists

Comment: How about all the pieces listed for the British ABRSM examination system?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you're still compiling... (Note: these are intended for performers and teachers, but should more than serve your purpose.)

McGrath, Jane. *Pianists Guide to Standard Teaching and Performance Literature*. Alfred Music, 1995.

Hinson, Maurice. *Guide to the Pianist's Repertoire*. 4th ed. Bloomington, IN: Indiana University Press, 2013.